# UML Arrow differences and Aggregation Question

Tags: uml

Whats the **difference** between the doted arrow line (Dependency) and the solid arrow line (Using) ?
Also is a aggregation (diamond shaped line) a implication that there are multiple objects of a class.

Like "Wheel is a Part of Car" , are there multiple wheels.
The name aggregation confuses me a bit

Comment: Better forget about aggregation at all. It's use is litte and the confusion it adds is big.

Comment: We use it in every UML diagramm at the University so just forgeting about it is not realy an option.

Comment: UML and university is kind of a scary combination. What they teach is usually on a low/bad level. Just judging from the questions that arive here.